# Why do axes transpose upon indexing?

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain this behavior?

```
>>> M = np.zeros((1,500,10))
>>> M.shape
(1, 500, 10)
>>> M[0,:,5:10].shape
(500, 5)
>>> M[0,:,np.arange(5,10)].shape
(5, 500)
```

Why are the axes flipped when indexing with an array instead of directly?

Comment: Hmmm... that's a puzzler.  All I can surmise is that ranges expressed directly like "5:10" are treated differently by the Numpy indexing mechanism than the same ranges expressed as lists, like "[5,6,7,8,9]" or "np.arange(5,10)"

Comment: Slicing using indices and ranges is called *basic slicing*, whils slicing using arrays (like the one resuling from `np.arange` is called *advanced slicing*. Your last example combines both basic and advanced slicing, which can result in pretty complex behaviours, as per [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing).

Comment: Another recent question about the same puzzle, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808302/numpy-slice-strange-behavior